# External stylesheets vs style tags with a php include

Tags: php, html, css, php-include

One of the things many web designers learn is that the more things you have that are external to a page, the longer it takes to fully load the page, because more server requests are made.

The most common way people style their pages is by using something along the lines of:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Which, of course, is a perfectly fine solution with no problems to it. However, it's a HTML-based call to an external file, which means the user requests an additional resource from the server.

Now correct me if I'm wrong here, but since PHP is server-side, if I were to use the `include` function to call an external file, the server would be the one to put the external file contents into the file it was called from, and then delivering the page to the user, without the user making additional requests.

If this is true, how feasible is this?

```
<head>
    <style>
        <?php include "style.css";?>
    </style>
</head>
```

While I'm aware that loading times for just one external call wouldn't make a world of difference, but as far as my line of thinking is concerned, is this correct, and is this an improvement over the common link rel method, even if by a small amount?

Regarding the include function, I'm aware that there are security issues, but let's just ignore those. If someone had access to your server to be able to exploit such a security risk, a little include function will be the least of your worries.

Comment: I think the major argument for this is caching. The resource is cached, whereas the php/html file is not.

Comment: i visit 10 pages of your site i load the external css once, your way i load the css in the html file  10 times

Comment: Does this issue also apply if your pages such as index.php use the include function to add all the code before the body tag, which would still include a link rel anyway?

Comment: Just want to echo the same sentiment: the benefits of the CSS file only being downloaded and cached once far outweigh that of one less initial resource request. Particularly if you have a large stylesheet.

Comment: go the whole hog embed images to `<img src="data:image/png;base64,`

Comment: How much of a difference does it make when most of the site content isn't cached? Everything that can be read (ie, words for the user) is stored in an array because the site has multiple languages. Either way, am I to assume then that there is no way to code in some sort of caching for these cases?

Comment: do you have a specific issue here, or are you just exploring they theory?

Comment: Mostly just the theory, but I'm contemplating its use on my sites as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonly, you are going for this method:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

because the browser is caching it.

You load the page once, and all external pathes are cached. When you reload the Page, you don't have to load anything again.

The 'include-method':

```
<head>
    <style>
        <?php include "style.css";?>
    </style>
</head>
```

loads the external stylesheet again and again, when you reload the page - nothing is cached!

Conclusion:

If you load the page just once, the include method is a little bit faster.
If you load the page more than just once, the HTML-link method is alot faster.

Comment: Just to quote my question in the comments above: Does this issue also apply if your pages such as index.php use the include function to add all the code before the body tag, which would still include a link rel anyway?

Comment: No - when you include a file with link rel - the browser caches it, the first time it is gonna included. but... it will include the link rel again and again^^. But it works :) the browser caches it. In big frameworks, for example typo3, there is a headerData.ts file, which got all link rel-s. Then they get included on the other sites :).

Comment: So, no way to cache it AND have the CSS internal to the file, then?  Nothing in PHP that can say 'cache the following:'?

Comment: Apologies. Going through some of my questions and I forgot to accept this answer. I don't suppose you could still answer my question in the comment above, could you?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand your question^^.

Comment: Basically is there a way to cache specified things with PHP, in the same manner than the `<link rel` tag does? Linking CSS externally and calling it with that tag will get it cached by the user, but if you use pure php and inline everything, it won't be cached. Is there anything you could do to inline the styles and get it cached, without resorting to adding your styles to each tag in your page (ie, `div`, `span`, etc)?